# When implementing Firebase (Flutter) notifications, I'm getting an error

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

First I apologize for not being a native speaker of the English language.

But the problem I'm having is as follows.

1) I am following a tutorial (Youtube / Documentation) to implement notifications in Flutter.

2) As directed by the documentation I made all the recommended settings. They are as follows:

- Generate google-services.json file in Console Flutter
- Add apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' to build.gradle in app folder
- Add classpath 'com.google.gms: google-services: 4.2.0' in build.gradle to root of android folder
- Add intent-filter (FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK) to AndroidManifest.xml file

This is the build.gradle of the android folder.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'        
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "26.1.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the build.gradle of the app folder.

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.tccversao2"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is my code

```
@immutable
class Message {
  final String title;
  final String body;

  const Message({
    @required this.title,
    @required this.body,
  });
}

class MessagingWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MessagingWidgetState createState() => _MessagingWidgetState();
}

class _MessagingWidgetState extends State<MessagingWidget> {
  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
  final List<Message> messages = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: $message");
        final notification = message['notification'];
        setState(() {
          messages.add(Message(
              title: notification['title'], body: notification['body']));
        });
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onLaunch: $message");

        final notification = message['data'];
        setState(() {
          messages.add(Message(
            title: '${notification['title']}',
            body: '${notification['body']}',
          ));
        });
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onResume: $message");
      },
    );
    _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
        const IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => ListView(
        children: messages.map(buildMessage).toList(),
      );

  Widget buildMessage(Message message) => ListTile(
        title: Text(message.title),
        subtitle: Text(message.body),
      );
}
```

I'm using the library
firebase_messaging: ^4.0.0+1
firebase_core: ^0.3.0

I am getting the following error message:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Android dependency 'com.android.support:support-fragment' has different version for the compile (26.1.0) and runtime (27.1.1) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I already tried to use in my build.gradle (in the android folder) the classpath 'com.google.gms: google-services: 4.3.0', but in this case I'm getting another error which is:

```
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "E:\Flutter\projetos\tcc_versao2\tcc_versao2\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'E:\Flutter\projetos\tcc_versao2\tcc_versao2\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> ASCII

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
  Command: E:\Flutter\projetos\tcc_versao2\tcc_versao2\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

*Maybe it is important to say: I am debugging on my phone (Xiaomi Note 3 pro)

I am completely lost on this mistake and would be very happy if anyone could help me.

Comment: After a lot of brains I found a solution, I will edit the code above and lay with the solution in case anyone else has this problem ...

1) Also add firebase_core: ^ 0.3.0 to pubspec.yaml
2) Add subprojects in build.gradle in android folder
3) In defaultConfig (build.gradle in app folder) add multiDexEnabled true

Now just be happy: D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at the libraries you are using.

The error says it found two different versions for `com.android.support:support-fragment`. Open your android/build.gradle and check if there is that dependency here and update it to version 27.1.1.

If you don't find the dependency directly in your app, it probably is coming from another outdated dependency or Flutter plugin. Verify for updates for all plugin dependencies at pubspec.yaml too.

Comment: In my android folder (build.gradle) there is no com.android.support:support-fragment dependency, just add it to dependencies?

My pubspec.yaml is apparently normal. The error just started appearing after I made the build.gradle changes to code notifications

Comment: Thanks for helping out, your answer has given me a great "direction" to follow for this fix although it is not entirely correct ...
I am very grateful for this!